# Why doesn't toString throw an exception when called on null value in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

Given the code

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val someText: String? = null
    println(someText.toString())
}
```

When run, output is

```
null
```

Two questions appear:

- is that possible to implement custom null-safe method with fallback to some default code (like, I think, toString does)
- why no exception is thrown?

Comment: Ok, but what about the second question? Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/to-string.html):

> ```
> fun Any?.toString(): String
> ```
>
> Returns a string representation of the object. Can be called with a null receiver, in which case it returns the string "null".

You can achieve similar behaviour by writing an [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html).  For example:

```
fun Any?.foo() = println(this ?: "Sadly, this is null")

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val x: Int? = null
    val y: Int? = 3

    x.foo()       // "Sadly, this is null"
    y.foo()       // "3"
    null.foo()    // "Sadly, this is null"
}
```

<sub>[Live example.](https://ideone.com/kCBLeH)</sub>

Comment: Interesting extension... calling `foo()` on any nullable object should work without having to first assert not null or `?.foo()`?

Comment: @RobinJonsson - Indeed.  I've edited my answer to include a more complete example.